# How to create 21 random groups of 10 people 4 times, without people being in the same group

Tags: pandas, random, slice, shuffle

I'm new to python and learning the hard way. I have a task that is quite tedious and i hope you can help me.

I am organising an event for 220 people. Throughout the day there are 4 activities. The activities are performed in teams of 10 people (22 teams). The goal is that for every activity the teams change. So, i want to rearrange the team composition 4 times. This is to make sure people get to know as many colleagues as possible.

In excel, i have a list of 220 names in column A. I assigned a number to each name (1 -220) in column B. I imported the modules random and pandas. My first step was to import the excel file, turn the column B with Numbers into a list and shuffled them.

After that step i'm lost. From the shuffles list i want to create the 22 teams. After the first draw, i want to shuffle the list again and create again 22 teams but with the condition that there are no people from the first team composition together in the second composition. In Total this process repeats itself for four times.

Ideally i would like to export the resulta back to excel.

Hope that someone can help me!

Again, i'm learning so please share the thought process:).

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,

Bas

Comment: consider to attach reproducible example of your dateframe. And provide your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use Pandas. It is the wrong tool for the job. Use NumPy instead. Here is a code:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: people = np.arange(1, 221, 1)
        people
Out[2]: array([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,
                 14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,
                 27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,
                 40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,  52,
                 53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65,
                 66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,
                 79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,
                 92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104,
                105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117,
                118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130,
                131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143,
                144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156,
                157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169,
                170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182,
                183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195,
                196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208,
                209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220])

In [3]: np.random.choice(people, 220, replace=False).reshape(22,10)
Out[3]: array([[ 20,  48, 164, 176, 135, 190,  67, 147, 203, 130],
               [150, 177, 171, 141, 122, 127, 202, 172,  21, 219],
               [167, 206,  84, 118, 163, 181,  34,  87, 116, 184],
               [ 33,  26,  70, 119, 129, 191, 105,  69,  86, 217],
               [ 94,  24, 146,   9,  31, 208, 179, 148,  57, 102],
               [211, 170,  65, 195, 220,  61,  88, 187,  32,   7],
               [182,  40, 144, 145, 198,  47, 193,  74,  44,  90],
               [174, 121, 216,  63,  82,  38, 201, 113,  13,  66],
               [180, 137, 214,  73,  75,  51,  80,  23,  71,  18],
               [161, 115,   3, 157,  89,  79,  29,  68, 200,   8],
               [142, 173,  98,  36, 133, 215, 138,  50,  53,   4],
               [152, 101, 139,  54,  30, 108,  49, 213, 124,  83],
               [ 76,  17,  64,  10,  56,  22, 128, 153, 158, 140],
               [131,  11,  45, 192,  92, 166,  60,  37,  12, 156],
               [104,  25,   6, 205, 212, 197,  77,  46, 199,  96],
               [ 59,  19, 112, 132, 126, 159, 151, 207,  85, 109],
               [ 42,  55, 204, 188, 185,  35,  62,  41,  27, 178],
               [ 14, 194,   2, 186, 143,  78, 134, 103, 106, 110],
               [100,  91,  99, 111,  72,  58,  15, 120, 136,  97],
               [ 39,  81, 123, 149, 165, 169, 209, 175,   1, 117],
               [189,  28,  95, 114, 162, 160, 196,   5,  93, 154],
               [210,  16, 168, 218,  43, 107, 155, 125,  52, 183]])
```

Notice that `Out[3]` is a matrix of 22 rows, and 10 columns (22 teams of 10 people each). You just need to run the code in `In [3]` as many times as the tasks you have. So basically:

```
In [4]: tasks = {} # Tasks is a dictionary with task number as key, and teams array as value.
        for i in np.range(1, 5, 1):
            tasks['task_' + str(i)] = np.random.choice(people, 220, replace=False).reshape(22,10)
```

Now, you can bring the result stored in `tasks` back into your Excel file, and proceed from there. Let me know if you have any concerns.

---

If you are adamant about using Pandas, and you already have the data loaded in `df`, then you can use Pandas to return the names of players for each team, for each task. This code should suffice for your needs:

```
df.set_index('player_id', inplace=True) # Which is actually pointless because
# Pandas will automatically create a 0 indexed index when you read your data in.
# So you don't even need any player_id column to begin with. If that is the case,
# change In [2] above to people = np.arange(0, 220, 1), or simply, np.arange(220)

tasks = {}
for i in np.arange(1, 5, 1):
    tasks['task_' + str(i)] = {}
    j = 1
    for team in np.random.choice(people, 220, replace=False).reshape(22,10):
      tasks[i]['team_' + str(j)] = df.loc[team].values
      j += 1
```

`tasks` at the end of this code, will be nested Dictionary, with a structure like:

```
tasks = {'task_1' : {'team_1'  : [list_of_players],
                     'team_2'  : [list_of_players],
                      ...
                     'team_19' : [list_of_players],
                     'team_20' : [list_of_players]},
         'task_1' : {'team_1'  : [list_of_players],
                     'team_2'  : [list_of_players],
                      ...
                     'team_19' : [list_of_players],
                     'team_20' : [list_of_players]},
         'task_1' : {'team_1'  : [list_of_players],
                     'team_2'  : [list_of_players],
                      ...
                     'team_19' : [list_of_players],
                     'team_20' : [list_of_players]},
         'task_1' : {'team_1'  : [list_of_players],
                     'team_2'  : [list_of_players],
                      ...
                     'team_19' : [list_of_players],
                     'team_20' : [list_of_players]}}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you arrange people not to meet twice?

Comment: If you really want to force that condition, there is a simple mathematical trick of shuffling people around after the first teams are built. I don't remember it off the top of my head, but I'll look for it and update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute-force algorithm - it depends on random selections, if it fails, it just tries it again.

Didn't used `pandas` at all, just ordinary lists and sets.

### How it works:

- pick a person to join the team
- if he already met someone, take him back and pick another guy
- otherwise let him join the team and update `met` variable of the whole team
- sometimes, as it happens, everyone remaining has already met someone in the team - in that case just don't bother and raise an exception

---

```
from random import choice

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.met = set()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class TooManyIteration(Exception):
    pass

GAMES = 4
TEAMS = 22
TEAMSIZE = 10

def pick_teams(s):
    s_ = s.copy()
    teams = [set() for _ in range(TEAMS)]
    for t in teams:
        c = 0
        while len(t) < TEAMSIZE:
            p = choice(tuple(s_))
            s_.remove(p)

            if all(p not in x.met for x in t):
                t.add(p)
            else:
                s_.add(p)

                c += 1
                if c > len(s):
                    # failed to pick
                    raise TooManyIteration()

    for t in teams:
        for x in t:
            x.met.update(t)

    return teams

s = set(Person(str(i)) for i in range(220))
# s = set(Person(name) for name in LIST_OF_NAMES)

games = []
while len(games) < GAMES:
    try:
        games.append(pick_teams(s))
    except TooManyIteration:
        continue
print(games)
```

Lucky you want only four games, I thing it has exponential complexity.